# Delphi: Access Nested Dataset master information when applying update

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

Can I access the parent dataset information (like `MyField.NewValue`) in the `BeforeUpdateRecord` event of a provider when applying the updates to the nested dataset?

Reason:

When I apply updates to a CDS that has a nested detail, the master PK is generated by the underlying query (`TIBCQuery`) and propagated to the master CDS.

But the new key is not visible  in the `BeforeUpdateRecord` of the detail as the field is updated in the `AfterUpdateRecord`:

```
DeltaDS.FieldByName(FieldName).NewValue := SourceDS.FieldByName(FieldName).NewValue)
```

and the delta is not merged yet.

It looks like the `DeltaDS` parameter of the `BeforeUpdateRecord` event contains only information to the nested dataset when the call occurs for the details.

It would be nice if I could do something like:

```
DeltaDS.ParentDS.FieldByName('FIELDNAME').NewValue.
```

**Edit:**

When using nested datasets the `BeforeUpdateRecord` event is called twice, once for the master and once for the detail (if we have one record of both). When the event is called for the detail, is there a way to access the master information contained in the `DeltaDS` ?

We can't access the data of the master CDS at that moment as the changes are not already merged. I hope this is not adding more confusion.

Comment: I am sure it is me, but could you please rephrase the question?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the provider's `Resolver` to look up the corresponding `TUpdateTree`:

```
function FindDeltaUpdateTree(Tree: TUpdateTree; DeltaDS: TCustomClientDataSet): TUpdateTree;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if Tree.Delta = DeltaDS then
    Result := Tree
  else
    for I := 0 to Tree.DetailCount - 1 do
    begin
      Result := FindDeltaUpdateTree(Tree.Details[I], DeltaDS);
      if Assigned(Result) then
        Break;
    end;
end;
```

You can use this in your `OnBeforeUpdate` handler:

```
var
  Tree, ParentTree: TUpdateTree;
begin
  if SourceDS = MyDetailDataSet then
  begin
    Tree := FindDeltaUpdateTree(TDataSetProvider(Sender).Resolver.UpdateTree, DeltaDS);
    if Assigned(Tree) then
    begin
      ParentTree := Tree.Parent;
      // here you can use ParentTree.Source (the dataset) and ParentTree.Delta (the delta)
    end;
  end;
end;
```